# Difficulty understanding Java MouseEvent

Tags: java

I'm doing these iTunes Stanford classes, and I've been learning beginning Java.  Things are going great, but they recently introduced events-and specifically MouseEvents.  I've been reading the chapters in the book, and pouring through the example code, and something is just not clicking right for me...it's always that asynchronous stuff that gives me trouble :-D

Earlier, some people mentioned it was important that I mention that the "addMouseListener" is a class in the Graphics import.  As far as I can tell, that just adds a blanket mouse listener to the canvas.

I'm still real new to this, so I may not be describing things as well as I should.

This is a piece of code that I have been trying to simplify in order to better understand it.  Currently, it will build a red rectangle, and I can click on it and drag it along the x axis.  Great!!!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

/** This class displays a mouse-draggable rectangle and oval */

public class DragObject extends GraphicsProgram {

    /* Build a rectangle  */
    public void run() {

        GRect rect = new GRect(100, 100, 150, 100);
        rect.setFilled(true);
        rect.setColor(Color.RED);
        add(rect);
        addMouseListeners();
    }

/** Called on mouse press to record the coordinates of the click */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        lastX = e.getX();
        lastY = e.getY();
        gobj = getElementAt(lastX, lastY);
    }

/** Called on mouse drag to reposition the object */
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { 

            if((lastX) > 100){
            gobj.move(e.getX() - lastX, 0);

            lastX = e.getX();
            lastY = e.getY();
        }
    }

/** Called on mouse click to move this object to the front */
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (gobj != null) gobj.sendToFront();
    }

/* Instance variables */
private GObject gobj;   /* The object being dragged */
private double lastX;   /* The last mouse X position */
private double lastY;   /* The last mouse Y position */
}
```

If I drag the mouse off the canvas, I want the rectangle to stay within the canvas, and not move off it (the same behavior that a horizontal scroll bar would do if you moved beyond the scroll area with the mouse button still clicked).  How can I do that?

I've been trying something along these lines, but it's not working right:

```
    if  ( ( lastX > (getWidth() - PADDLE_WIDTH) ) || ( lastX < PADDLE_WIDTH ) ) {
        gobj.move(0, 0);
    } else {
        gobj.move(e.getX() - lastX, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is moving the rectangle relative to the last position of the mouse. This works fine when you are simply moving things, but for your needs when you want it to stop at the borders, you need to use absolute positioning.

```
// When the mouse is pressed, calculate the offset between the mouse and the rectangle
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    lastX = e.getX();
    lastY = e.getY();
    gobj = getElementAt(lastX, lastY);
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { 
        double newX;

        // Assuming you can get the absolute X position of the object.
        newX = gobj.getX() + e.getX() - lastX;
        // Limit the range to fall within your canvas. Adjust for your paddle width as necessary.
        newX = Math.max( 0, Math.min( newX, getWidth() ) );
        // Set the new position of the paddle, assuming you can set the absolute position.
        gobj.setX( newX );

        lastX = e.getX();
        lastY = e.getY();
    }
}
```

This may not be quite what you want because as soon as you go off the edge, the object will stop moving, but then once you move back toward the canvas, your paddle will move immediately instead of waiting for the mouse to reach the same relative position to the paddle at which it started.

You can probably experiment to get it to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you will need to know the width of the Canvas object, i'm sure there will be a method that will provide this value.  You can then check the current x location of the MouseEvent against the width of the canvas, and not increment the x coordinates of the shape object once you are past the width of the canvas.  Depending on how much of the shape you want to remain in the canvas, you may need to take into account the width of the shape object as well.

One thing that helps me when dealing w/ animation and moving objects in a gui is drawing out a few scenarios on paper, and noting how the coordinates change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I do have the canvas width.  The difficulty (to me) is that the animation is only moving the object in relation to it's past coordinate-not in relation to the canvas. gobj.move(e.getX() - lastX, 0);  So I've been trying things like if(lastX < 0){ lastX = 0} but that is just doing funky things in relation to the mouse movement-not the canvas :(